# Equivalency of closure expressions in Swift, such as with SKAction completion

Tags: swift, lambda, sprite-kit, closures, swift2

Are the following closure expressions equivalent?

```
sprite.runAction(action, completion: {
    print("done")
})

sprite.runAction(action, completion: {() -> Void in
    print("done")
})

sprite.runAction(action) {() -> Void in
    print("done")
}
```

In the example above using SpriteKit's [`runAction()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:completion:) with completion block, presumably the first example is implicit; however, it's the third example I'm not sure I understand.

In the third example, the function `runAction()` doesn't return anything; so, how is the completion block called when the action completes?

Comment: They are all equivalent. The last one uses a ["trailing closure"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your example are equivalent.

```
sprite.runAction(action, completion: {
    print("done")
})
```

is a short form of

```
sprite.runAction(action, completion: {() -> Void in
    print("done")
})
```

omitting the parameter and return type declaration,
because the type of the closure can be
[inferred from the context](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID98)
(here: from the type of the `completion:` parameter).

Finally,

```
sprite.runAction(action) {() -> Void in
    print("done")
}
```

is identical to the second one, but uses the
["trailing closure syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).